# can JavaScript create a new function based on user input?

Tags: javascript, html, function, user-defined-functions, element

I have an input box, and a button and other random elements in the HTML document. my question is this: *can JavaScript use an id that is entered into the input box and hide the element with that Id when the button is clicked?* please let me know how to do this. I am making a program that creates elements based on certain button clicks, so the user can format html without knowing code. I am trying to add dynamic functions and I have absolutely no idea what to do, because the functions need to be flexible enough to use the input in them.

the reason I can't insert the functions directly is because I want the button to use a function that is specifically created to do what the user wants.

I also dont know jquery, inly HTML JavaScript and CSS

Comment: Yes, it can. What have you tried?

Comment: yes, thats perfectly doable. please upload the code you have so far, so that suggestions can be made based on your current implementation

Comment: [You'll need to show us what you have tried, and where you are exactly stuck](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/182380#182380). Please update your post with a [Short, Self-contained, Correct example](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: very simple with jQuery `$('#'+id).hide()`

Comment: @FlushFish: Oh for cryin' out loud, not like it's hard directly with the DOM, either. I don't have anything against jQuery, I'm just sayin'...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder jQuery is worth to mention I guess... therefore I haven't answered the question, just commented it, I'm just sayin'...

Comment: "the reason I can't insert the functions directly is because I want the button to use a function that is specifically created to do what the user wants." — Stop wanting that. You don't need it to solve the problem you've described. It only makes things more complicated for no benefit.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but you are on entirely the wrong track: you don't need to create a new function in response to user input to do that.

You just need to use user input in a function.

```
function myEventHandler(event) {
    var user_input = document.getElementById('my_text_input').value;
    var user_selected_element = document.getElementById(user_input);
    if (user_selected_element) {
        user_selected_element.style.display = "none";
    }
}

document.getElementById('the_button').addEventListener('click', myEventHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a function that is passed to the button's click handler. When the button is clicked, we can get the input's value and process it from there. Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zp347o6h/).

```
function hideById() {
  var id = document.getElementById('id').value;
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", hideById);
```